# Run python function in azure without flask

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-appservice, azure-python-sdk

I want to run a python script in Azure without using flask or jango. I'm thinking about azure functions or something like this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use [Azure functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/functions/#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20Functions%20%201%20Create%20reliable%20serverless,30%20days.%20While%20you%20have%20your...%20More%20) in this case. Alternatively, you can also use Azure web jobs where you can upload it through the [web job blade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateContinuous) by creating your app service in the VS code zipping it.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [function in Azure with Python using Visual Studio Code - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python)
2. [WebJobs - github wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs)

Comment: Azure Function App gives a server by default. You can see this because a route annotation is needed.